# Copy IEnumerable, replacing an item

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, yield-return

I want to make a copy of an `IEnumerable<T>` in which a single item at a given index has been replaced by a given value.

I defined the following method which does what I want:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item, int index)
{
    foreach (T before in source.Take(index))
    {
        yield return before;
    }

    yield return item;

    foreach (T after in source.Skip(index + 1))
    {
        yield return after;
    }
}
```

However, while perhaps easy to understand, it seems 'inefficient' to create two iterators, one of which skips the items already taken by the first iterator.

Is there a better way of defining this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item, int index)
{
    return source.Select((value, i) => index == i ? item : value);
}
```

Comment: Well, fair. This answer war earler than mine :)

Comment: @tym32167 Barely, but I upvoted your answer anyway. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about efficient, but have you tried this?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item, int index)
{
    return source.Select((x, i) => i == index ? item : x);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, two identical answers within 10 seconds of each other. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson :D nice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go crazy, you can unroll the `foreach` manually:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item, int index)
{
    int itemIndex = 0;
    using(var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while(iter.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return itemIndex++ == index ? item : iter.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better than doing the same using `foreach`? I.e. `int itemIndex = 0;
    foreach (var value in source)
    {
            yield return itemIndex++ == index ? item : value;
    }`.

Comment: @svick fair enough, that would be about the same; I guess in my head I'm used to more nuanced examples, but yes, in hindsight, this one is pretty simple